# WPA2-Enterprise and RADIUS accounting server

Tags: ubuntu, radius, access-point, freeradius

Is mandatory to use WPA2-Enterprise to be able to send accounting packages to my RADIUS server from an access point (Meraki)?

Comment: Did you ask your vendor?

Comment: I asked the Meraki guys and they made available the option to send accounting messages from my access points to my Radius server using an "open + sign on splash page" network (without WPA,WPA2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use WPA or WPA2.  Basically, WPA 1/2 enterprise is a friendly way of saying 802.1x authentication.  As for accounting vs authorazation, that all depends on the device.  Typically you don't need to send accounting packages, if that's what your asking.